# Solving $3\sin (x)- \tan(x) = -\sqrt{3} \sin(x)\tan(x) - \tan(x)$. Why are $0$ and $\pi$ solutions?

Tags: trigonometry

> For $0\leq x < 2\pi$, solve
>
> $$3\sin (x)- \tan(x) = -\sqrt{3} \sin(x)\tan(x) - \tan(x)$$

The solutions were $0, \frac{2}{3}\pi, \pi$ and $\frac{5}{3}\pi$, and I don't understand why $0$ and $\pi$ are solutions.

My solution;

$$3\sin (x)- \tan(x) = -\sqrt{3} \sin(x)\tan(x) - \tan(x)$$
$$3\sin (x) = -\sqrt{3} \sin(x)\tan(x)$$
$$3 = -\sqrt{3} \sin(x)\tan(x)$$
$$3 = -\sqrt{3} \tan(x)$$
$$\frac{3}{-\sqrt{3}} = \tan(x)$$
$$\tan(x) = -\sqrt{3}$$
$$x=\frac{2}{3}\pi , \frac{5}{3}\pi$$

Comment: Show us your solution -- perhaps we'll be able to tell you where the misunderstanding takes place.

Comment: Do you not see that if you substitute in $0$ or $\pi$ you get $0$ on both sides of the equation?

Comment: Note that $\sin(x)$ can be zero.

Comment: It looks like you canceled a factor of $\sin x$ from both sides of the equation, but doing so eliminates the solutions in which $\sin x = 0$.  Also, your third line is not equivalent to the second line since you omitted the $\sin x$ on the left-hand side of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align}
3\sin x-\tan x&=-\sqrt3\sin x\tan x-\tan x\tag 1\\
3\sin x&=-\sqrt3\sin x\tan x\\
3\sin x+\sqrt3\sin x\tan x&=0\\
\sqrt3\sin x(\sqrt3+\tan x)&=0\tag2
\end{align}
The zero-product property states that $$\text{If}\ ab=0, \text{then}\ a=0\ \text{or}\ b=0.$$
The manipulation of $(1)$ into $(2)$ allows us to solve $(1)$ by applying the zero-product property to $(2)$, which requires you to solve both $\sqrt3\sin x=0$ AND $\sqrt3+\tan x=0$ to get all the solutions to $(1)$.  We therefore have $\boxed{x=0,\frac{2\pi}3,\pi,\frac{5\pi}3}$ as desired.